# Unir elementos similares a uno solo con javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo el siguiente array en el cual existen varios elementos que poseen los mismos datos pero difieren en uno en especifico, como se podría combinar los datos para que se vena juntos en un mismo registro?

```
[
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "albañil"
  },
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "carpintero"
  },
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "mecanico"
  }
]
```

Como podria unificar el array para que se viera de la siguiente manera:

```
[
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: [
      "albañil",
      "carpintero",
      "mecanico"
    ] 
  }
]
```

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer una iteración de datos al arreglo y luego formar uno nuevo a partir de un objeto nuevo, como podrás ver haces un foreach donde le pasas los primeros 2 valores del arreglo y el contenido de todo el objeto profesión (...rest) iterado, luego insertas en el objeto los datos dentro de una nueva variable llamada profesión.

##### Código de prueba

```js
const array=[
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "albañil"
  },
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "carpintero"
  },
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "mecanico"
  }
]

const otro = {};

array.forEach(({ nombre, apellido, ...rest }) => {
  otro[nombre] = otro[nombre] || { nombre, apellido, profesion: [] };
  otro[nombre].profesion.push(rest.profesion)
})

console.log(Object.values(otro))
```

**Edit:**
En caso de querer considerar también el apellido, suponiendo que dos personas distintas tengan el mismo nombre con diferente apellido puedes agregar esta modificación:

```javascript
    otro[nombre+'_'+apellido] = otro[nombre+'_'+apellido] || { nombre, apellido, profesion: [] };
    otro[nombre+'_'+apellido].profesion.push(rest.profesion)
```

##### Código de prueba

```js
const array=[
    {
      nombre: "eduardo",
      apellido: "lopez",
      profesion: "albañil"
    },
    {
      nombre: "eduardiño",
      apellido: "lopez",
      profesion: "carpintero2"
    },
    {
      nombre: "eduardo",
      apellido: "lopez",
      profesion: "mecanico"
    },
    {
      nombre: "eduardiño",
      apellido: "franco",
      profesion: "mecanico2"
    }
  ]
  
  const otro = {};
  
  array.forEach(({ nombre, apellido, ...rest }) => {
    otro[nombre+'_'+apellido] = otro[nombre+'_'+apellido] || { nombre, apellido, profesion: [] };
    otro[nombre+'_'+apellido].profesion.push(rest.profesion)
  })
  
  console.log(Object.values(otro))
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma, si ya sabes cuales son los datos que se repiten, podrías hacer este código mas sencillo...

```
const array = [
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "albañil"
  },
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "carpintero"
  },
  {
    nombre: "eduardo",
    apellido: "lopez",
    profesion: "mecanico"
  }
]

const profesiones = array.map(item => item.profesion);

const finalData = {
  nombre : array[0].nombre,
  apellido : array[0].apellido,
  profesion : [...profesiones]
}

console.log(finalData);
```